# Firebase - how to find all the match items with auto-generated ID, where values are false

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following the techniques on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Given the url root is: https://myApp.firebaseio.com

And the data is:

```
  // Tracking two-way relationships between users and groups
  {
    "users": {
      "mchen": {
        "name": "Mary Chen",
        "groups": {
           "alpha": true,
           "bob": false, // <- I want this
           "charlie": true,
           "dave": false // <- I want this
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    "groups": {
      "alpha": {
        "name": "Alpha Group",
        "members": {
          "mchen": true,
          "hmadi": true
        }
      },
      ...
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to construct a Firebase query to find all the groups that have the value 'false' for user "mchen" (basically I want bob and dave)? How?

e.g. new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users/mchen/groups') ...

In my real code, alpha, bob, charlie and dave are Firebase auto-generated keys, but the same query should solve my problem. (I'm using Firebase Web version)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The [documentation on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) should contain all you need to know. Also: don't copy JSON from the docs and then say that your data is different. Either show your data or write the question in a way that makes such things irrelevant.

Comment: I have done lots of research and tried really hard. Posts like https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html doesn't seem to solve my problem. I know what I have in here is slightly different from the doc, but I'm just trying to put a post that simplifies the data and people feel more familiar with. If you have a solution to this problem, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. I'm not an expert, but I hope this helps anybody not familiar with Firebase:

If you only use Firebase:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users/mchen/groups');
ref.orderByValue().equalTo(false).on('value', function(data){
  console.log(data.val());
})
```

If you use AngularFire:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/users/mchen/groups');
$firebaseArray(ref.orderByValue().equalTo(false)).$loaded().then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Note:

- orderByValue() is the one to use without knowing the keys
- Use equalTo(false), not equalTo('false')
- $firebaseArray is the one that returns multi items, not $firebaseObject

A rule is also required for performance:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userName": { // A better way would be using an auto-generated ID in here
        "groups": {
          ".indexOn" : ".value" // add index on the value - notice it's .value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```